# new format of keepass (2) database file and hashcat

Tags: hashcat, keepass

I created test DB file (.kdbx) using KeePassX, after that used keepass2john Python port from this [site](https://gist.github.com/HarmJ0y/116fa1b559372804877e604d7d367bbc), but changed line 88:

```
index += 2
```

to

```
index += 4
```

because the size of this field is 4 bytes instead of 2 (program will show wrong results without this change). It outputs `test.hash`:

`$keepass$*2*0*253*e73cfb2502b6e543902ec7db45c751195c3dd8b8531b744537cbeebd8c641ecd**59ac17e7e0a201e1fae906371d65f6c6**8753d87e52c88988d168c9a4c75e76febecc74fd6ba40c7254d1c47f672d5bbf`

After that, I used `hashcat, v. 5.1.0` with:

`hashcat -a 0 -m 13400 test.hash example.dict`

In output i see an error:

```
Hashfile 'test.hash' on line 1 ($keepa...becc74fd6ba40c7254d1c47f672d5bbf): 
Token length exception
No hashes loaded.
```

What's wrong? Keepass changed format of DB file and hashcat can't correctly crack it?

Comment: In this case, you need to know what hashcat expects to be the length. They provide examples for the different formats here: https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes

Comment: yeah, and i 've changed `*0*` to `*6000*`. like they advice but still got this error.

Comment: are the rest of the fields within the size expectations? one of them won't be

Comment: unfortunately, no, cause some fields are empty (there are no such parameters in `.kdbx` file)

Comment: and that's your likely problem

Comment: either the Python port messed up or hashcat doesn't have a format for this

Comment: but how can i correctly provide correct string to haschat without some parameters?

Answer (score 3):

This question was cross-posted on the hashcat GitHub and answered [here](https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat/issues/2195).

The relevant [keepass2john comments](https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper/blob/ea33667eb5e1a650ecb6b4985125f4efa0955594/src/keepass2john.c#L81) say that only versions prior to KeePass 2.36 are supported for conversion.

Newer versions may use Argon2 or ChaCha20, but hashcat does not support these at this writing. See also related posts on the [John the Ripper GitHub issue](https://github.com/openwall/john/issues/2502).